# Can't rotate a shape in Javafx

Tags: javafx

I'm having trouble rotating a shape in JavaFX. Here's some code in which I want the arrowhead to point in the same direction as the line (yes, I will be adding a translation later, to put it on the end of the line, but one thing at a time).

The `println` statement is showing me that `theta` is updating correctly as I move the start and end points around, but the arrowhead stays stubbornly at the original angle. Is there another step I have to do in order to get shape to rotate, or should I be doing it a different way?

```
package application.view;

public class Connector extends Group {
    private final DoubleProperty startX;
    private final DoubleProperty startY;
    private final DoubleProperty endX;
    private final DoubleProperty endY;

    public Connector(Line line, Polygon arrowhead, Preferences prefs) {
        arrowhead.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        arrowhead.setStrokeWidth(1);
        arrowhead.setFill(Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE);
        startX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        startY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        endX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        endY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        thetaBinding = new DoubleBinding() {
            {
                super.bind(startX, startY, endX, endY);
            }
            @Override
            protected double computeValue() {
                return Math.atan2(getEndY() - getStartY(), getEndX() - getStartX());
            }
        };

        theta = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        theta.bind(thetaBinding);

        theta.addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,
                    Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                System.out.println(newValue);
                arrowhead.rotateProperty().set((Double)newValue);
            }
        });

        lineLength = new DoubleBinding() {
            {
                super.bind(startX, startY, endX, endY);
            }
            @Override
            protected double computeValue() {
                return Math.hypot(getEndX() - getStartX(), getEndY() - getStartY()) - prefs.getDouble("CONNECTOR_ARROW_LENGTH", Defaults.CONNECTOR_ARROW_LENGTH);
            }
        };

        lineEndX = new DoubleBinding() {
            {
                super.bind(startX, lineLength, theta);
            }
            @Override
            protected double computeValue() {
                return startX.get() + lineLength.get() * Math.cos(theta.get());
            }
        };

        lineEndY = new DoubleBinding() {
            {
                super.bind(startY, lineLength, theta);
            }
            @Override
            protected double computeValue() {
                return startY.get() + lineLength.get() * Math.sin(theta.get());
            }
        };

        arrowhead.getPoints().setAll(new Double[] {
                0.0, 0.0,
                0.0, prefs.getDouble("CONNECTOR_ARROW_HALF_WIDTH", Defaults.CONNECTOR_ARROW_HALF_WIDTH),
                prefs.getDouble("CONNECTOR_ARROW_LENGTH", Defaults.CONNECTOR_ARROW_LENGTH), 0.0,
                0.0, -prefs.getDouble("CONNECTOR_ARROW_HALF_WIDTH", Defaults.CONNECTOR_ARROW_HALF_WIDTH),
        });

        line.startXProperty().bind(startX);
        line.startYProperty().bind(startY);
        line.endXProperty().bind(lineEndX);
        line.endYProperty().bind(lineEndY);

        getChildren().addAll(line, arrowhead);
    }

    public final DoubleBinding thetaBinding;
    public final DoubleProperty theta;
    public final DoubleBinding lineLength;
    public final DoubleBinding lineEndX;
    public final DoubleBinding lineEndY;

    public double getStartX() {
        return startX.get();
    }

    public void setStartX(double value) {
        startX.set(value);
    }

    public DoubleProperty startXProperty() {
        return startX;
    }

    public double getStartY() {
        return startY.get();
    }

    public void setStartY(double value) {
        startY.set(value);
    }

    public DoubleProperty startYProperty() {
        return startY;
    }

    public double getEndX() {
        return endX.get();
    }

    public void setEndX(double value) {
        endX.set(value);
    }

    public DoubleProperty endXProperty() {
        return endX;
    }

    public double getEndY() {
        return endY.get();
    }

    public void setEndY(double value) {
        endY.set(value);
    }

    public DoubleProperty endYProperty() {
        return endY;
    }
    }
```

Comment: The `rotate` property in JavaFX works with degrees, not with radians; the change is there, but it's to minor to recognize (smaller than 3.2°) You could use a binding instead of a listener to fix this in a pretty simple way: `arrowhead.rotateProperty().bind(theta.multiply(180 / Math.PI))` (Usually you'd use `Math.toDegrees` to do this convertion)

Comment: @fabian Will this binding expression not be garbage collected if you directly write it this way?

Comment: @mipa Quoting the [Property.bind() javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html#bind-javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue-): "Note that JavaFX has all the bind calls implemented through weak listeners. This means the bound property can be garbage collected and stopped from being updated."

Comment: @AustinSchäfer Exactly, that is what I was referring to. Therefore the binding should be stored in a separate variable which has the same lifetime as the arrowhead. Otherwise the binding may stop working after the first garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks to @fabian that was it, but I can't upvote your answer because it's a comment rather than a reply.

I'm not sure I understand the garbage collection issue - as far as I can see, all the bindings have the lifetime of the connection object. Once that goes out of scope, there's no relationship between the arrowhead and the line, so the bindings would become irrelevant anyway. Have I missed something?